# Order stacked ggplot2 percentage bar plot by y continuous value - repost

Tags: r, ggplot2

(reposted - previously flagged as duplicate but additional MRE illustrates issue more completely)

I'm trying to order one of the factors in a stacked percentage bar plot by the percentage value of that factor but can't manage to work out how to do it.

e.g. in the following I'd like the categories in `x` to be ordered by the percentage value of factor `q`.

```
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)

df <- tibble(x = rep(LETTERS[1:5], 2), y = c(10,20,5,60,30,90,80,95,40,70), z = c(rep("p", 5), rep("q", 5)))

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = z)) +
   geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "fill") +
   scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::percent)
```

[image]

The solution accepted at question [Reorder bars in geom_bar ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25664367/2802810) uses `reorder()` to change the order of x bars, but does not work for my case:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = reorder(x, -y), y = y, fill = z)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "fill") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::percent)
```

Produces exactly the same plot as above.

I think the reason is that the data are in tidy format so there are multiple y values for x, but I can't figure out how to map only a subset of y onto x.

Comment: set the levels in `x` to be `c("C", "A", "B", "E", "D")`

Comment: I need to do this programmatically. My real world need has many more cases that the toy example and is for automated reporting purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about first defining the levels:

```
df %>%
  filter(z == "q") %>%
  mutate(x = factor(x, levels = x[order(y)])) %>%
  pull(x) %>%
  levels -> x_levels
```

and then using those levels as input to ggplot:

```
df %>%
  mutate(x = factor(x,
                    levels = x_levels)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x,
             y = y,
             fill = z)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           position = "fill") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

[image]

another way is to use two accessory functions:

available on github [dgrtwo/drlib](https://github.com/dgrtwo/drlib/blob/master/R/reorder_within.R)

```
reorder_within <- function(x, by, within, fun = mean, sep = "___", ...) {
  new_x <- paste(x, within, sep = sep)
  stats::reorder(new_x, by, FUN = fun)
}


scale_x_reordered <- function(..., sep = "___") {
  reg <- paste0(sep, ".+$")
  ggplot2::scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) gsub(reg, "", x), ...)
}


ggplot(df, aes(x = reorder_within(x, y, 1, fun = max),
               y = y,
               fill = z)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           position = "fill") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+
  scale_x_reordered()
```

[image]

I used 1 as within group, but these functions allow for a [more complicated sort within each facet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47573036/r-reorder-factor-levels-for-several-individual-plots/47573652#47573652).

or:

```
  ggplot(df, aes(x = reorder_within(x, y, 1, fun = min),
                   y = y,
                   fill = z)) + 
      geom_bar(stat = "identity",
               position = "fill") +
      scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+
      scale_x_reordered()
```

[image]

Comment: Super stuff. The `levels` approach is really simple and I'll use, but I can see that the helper functions can offer more.